# objc[29733]: Swift class extensions and categories on Swift classes are not allowed to have +load methods xcode 10.2 running on ios 12.2

Tags: swift

I updated my Xcode to Version 10.2 (10E125) and my existing swift project crashes with "objc[29733]: Swift class extensions and categories on Swift classes are not allowed to have +load methods" while running in iPhoneX simulator 12.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was due to incompatible version of pod library for Xcode 10.2. Solved by updating all the library with version compatible to Xcode 10.2.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently in iOS 12.2 you can't use anymore `+ (void) load`.

You should refactor your code to use `__attribute__` instead of `+ (void) load`.

The old answer was given incorrectly but has good talk material to understand the problem.

I ask to any Developer to give a better answer that this one. I reckon my lack of knowledge is a speed bump on this answer but my idea is to at least start giving some insight on how to solve it! 
If at least one developer can make is code work, my job here is done :)

===============================Old Answer==================================

It's a known bug.
It seems the new 12.2 don't allow some method's to load swift modules.

A Fix was already made, let's hope it enters the react native 59.3. (Fingers Crossed.)

For more information:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24139

There are some temporary work arounds pls check the link above.

=============================EDIT old answer===============================

react-native 59.3 was released a few moments ago with this bug fixed, pls update.

Comment: Yes it is Swift but if you use Swift in React-Native, you get this error.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone encountering this error in a React Native project with Xcode 10.2, check that you are using [version 0.59.3](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.59.3) or later of `react-native`, which includes [a fix](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/df7ea67) for [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24139), which is related to using `RCT_EXTERN_MODULE` for Swift classes.